# Accessing and Sending raw image data to API

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I need to be able to access the raw image data from a loaded photo. Originally we were supposed to use Base64, however the API creator has changed it to raw image data.

In SWIFT, how would I accomplish the following?

[image: Raw image data]

I'm currently using Alamofire for my networking, but I'm not sure that it will work for this part of the API.

I already have the image resource as a variable to access, I just need to know how to get the raw data, and then formulate a POST request with just that data as the body of the request. A method with a callback would be awesome.

Comment: How does the api handle the image on upload? Usually you handle it as a file in a form and to download it you use NSData(contentsOfURL: ) and then UIImage(data: )

Answer (score 0):

`UIImagePNGRepresentation`

`UIImageJPEGRepresentation`

These method can encode a `UIImage` to `NSData`.

upload code:

```
Alamofire.upload(.POST, "http://your.org/upload", data: imageData)
```